# Drag and drop with css zoom

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, zooming

Yesterday i got a problem with my drag and drop. Thanks EdenSource for the fast help.

Today i want to zoom out/in. I use css3 zoom for this.

In this fiddle you see my problem. If you try to move a element with jQuery ui draggable the helper is on another position as my coursor.

This is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".card").draggable({   helper: "clone",
                             cursorAt: { top: 76, left: 101 },
                             opacity: 0.5,
                             scroll:true,
                             refreshPositions: true,
                            scrollSensitivity: 100});
    $(".card__dropzone--inner").droppable({
        activeClass: "card__dropzone--active",
        over: function(event) {
            $(this).animate({
                width: "250px"
            }, 200);
            console.log("over");
        },
        out: function(event) {
            console.log("now?!");
            $(event.target).animate({
                width: "25px"
            },200);
            console.log("out");
        },
        drop: function(event) {
            console.log("drop");
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mp085ead/2/

How could i get my helper back in the middle of my coursor while using css3 zoom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly found a solution.

jQuery-UI is not able to work with zoom. Even zoom is not the best way to zoom into objects.

A better way is to use a library like dragular or tweenmax. Both are able to drag/drop while the css-zoom is not 1.

But we decided to use transform scale.